# Android - ListView that looks like 'settings'

Tags: android, layout

I would like to create a listview that looks like 'Settings' in Android (i.e. If I click "Sound & Display" item, it will show items such as "silent mode, ringer volume, etc"). It looks like PreferenceScreen but this time, it doesn't configure anything.

A clearer example:
What I wanted was when an item category is selected -- let's say, Hospitals --, it calls another listview which contains a roster of hospitals around the area. When one of the items in the roster is selected, it will execute the call intent and dial the number. And if I wanted to go back to the list, I will just press the back button then see other categories.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,
[Android Preferences](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html)

And Also 
[Android - creating a custom preferences activity screen](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2010/12/03/android---creating-a-custom-preferences-activity-screen.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Needed this. I'll figure out if PreferenceScreen is the one I'm looking for. :)

Comment: Since PreferenceActivity is extends ListActivity class in android you can add PreferenceActivity in tab.